# How to add another option tag after you select a option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to create a loockup folder and if I use ul and li is going to expand my folders and subfolders. But to make it bit clear I decided to use option tag. But now the only options I have is the first parent of folders. I want to know how to add a option tag for the folders that are already in the folder selected before?

For example:

```
<select id="parent-folder">
     <option>folder1</option>
     <option>folder2</option>
<select>
<!--after you select one folder to show the folder inside that I want another option tag-->
 <select id="child-folder">
     <option>folder1</option>
     <option>folder2</option>
     <option>folder3</option>
     <option>folder4</option>
<select>
```

This is my JS code:

```
function processNewData( respObj, $menuElement, strCurrentPath ) {
    if ( (respObj.subfolders.length > 0) || (respObj.subswfs.length > 0) ) {
        var htmlExpand = 
                ( 'OPTION' === $menuElement.prop("tagName")  ? 
                    '<select class="submenu-item" data-path="' + strCurrentPath + '">' 
                    : '' );

        for( var i = 0; i < respObj.subfolders.length; i++ ) {
            var subfolder = respObj.subfolders[i];

            htmlExpand += 
                '<option ' + 
                    'data-type="path" ' + 
                    'data-path="' + strCurrentPath + '/' + subfolder + '" ' + 
                    'class="folder-item" ' + 
                    'onclick="menuFolderClick(this)"><div>' + 
                        subfolder + 
                '</div></option>';
        }

        for( var i = 0; i < respObj.subswfs.length; i++ ) {
            var subswf = respObj.subswfs[i];

            htmlExpand += 
                '<option ' + 
                    'data-type="swf" ' + 
                    'data-path="' + strCurrentPath + '/' + subswf + '" ' + 
                    'class="swf-item" ' + 
                    'onclick="menuSwfClick(this)"><div>' + 
                        subswf + 
                '</div></option>';
        }
        htmlExpand += ( 'OPTION' === $menuElement.prop("tagName")  ? '</select>' : '' );
        $menuElement.append( htmlExpand );
    }

    if ( 'OPTION' === $menuElement.prop("tagName") ) {
        $menuElement[0].removeAttribute("onclick");
    }
}
```

And this is what I have in HTML

```
<select id="menu"></select>
```

Comment: Could you explain graphically, what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just created Sample, think might help you. Change as per your requirement.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npdzhf7j/1)

**HTML**

```
<select id="menu">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Folder</option>    
    <option value="menu1">Folder 1 </option>
    <option value="menu2">Folder 2 </option>    
</select>

<select id="menu1">
    <option value="sub1">Sub Folder 1.1 </option>
    <option value="sub2">Sub Folder 1.2 </option>
    <option value="sub3">Sub Folder 1.3 </option>
</select>

<select id="menu2">
    <option value="sub1">Sub Folder 2.1 </option>
    <option value="sub2">Sub Folder 2.2 </option>
    <option value="sub3">Sub Folder 2.3 </option>
</select>
```

**JS/JQuery**

```
$("#menu1, #menu2").hide();
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var x = this.value
    $("#menu1, #menu2").hide();
    $("#" + x).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: @Marius Hincu Feel free to ask if you need explanation.